# relloc behavior on resize

Tags: c, memory-management

How does relloc behaves when it has to resize the allocated memory to a bigger size and it   has to be done in a separate memory area as the requested amount of memory can be resized   inplace. Does the original memory is deallocated automatically by relloc (I would think so  ) or it has to be done by the programmer (not likely) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `realloc` automatically handles freeing the original memory.  If the memory block can be resized in place, then `realloc` will do so.  If not, it will allocate a new memory block that is large enough, copy the data from the old block to the new, and free the old block.  You don't have to worry about freeing it yourself.

If `realloc` fails (e.g. you asked for way too much memory, and it couldn't allocate that much), then the original memory is *NOT* freed.  If you're not careful, you can leak memory -- if `realloc` returns NULL due to a failure and you don't keep a pointer to the original memory block, that memory will remain allocated and leak.